# Trying to pass value from ASP.NET JavaScript script to my C# Code Behind function using Hidden Field

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a JavaScript script inside my ASP.NET Web site, and i want to get a value from a function in my C# Code Behind, with a argument i pass it from my ASP.NET Hidden Field.

Here is my ASP.NET & JavaScript part, i define a HiddenField and assigns the `chatMessage` var to it, than assigns a value to the var, and try to send its value to the `returnLiClass()` function.
 (Important part is the first line, and the 13,14,17 lines):

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="chatMessage" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            // Html encode display name and message.
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div /> ').text(message).html();
            var tremp_id = $('<div /> ').text("<%=Request.QueryString["trempid"]%>").html();

            var chatMessage = document.getElementById('<%= chatMessage.ClientID %>');
            chatMessage.value = 'value from javascript';

            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#discussion').append('<li class="<%=returnLiClass(chatMessage.Value)%><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + "Tremp:" + tremp_id + '</li>');
        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val('<%=returnName()%>');
        // Set initial focus to message input box.
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The Code Behind function (When i debug neither the `msg` nor the `chatMessage.Value` has values):

```
protected String returnLiClass(String msg)
{
    String test = chatMessage.Value;
    return "redChat";
}
```

I'm not sure what am i doing wrong...
Hope you could help, Thank you!

Comment: You've included the inline code of `<%=returnLiClass(chatMessage.Value)%>` in the javascript.  I just want to confirm that you understand that this line will be run ONCE when the page is rendered, and will NOT be changed until the page is rendered by ASP.NET again?

Comment: @freefaller yes i'm aware to that, but with the given code the `msg` sent to the function should be 'value from javascript' anyway, shouldn't it?

Comment: How can it be the *value from javascript*?  At the point the ASP.NET renders the inline code-block, the javascript is purely conceptual, it hasn't run, it's simply text to send to the browser.  Once at the browser **then** the javascript will run... by which time the inline block doesn't exist, only the **result** of the inline block.  I think you're getting confused about exactly **when** each bit of the jigsaw actually executes

Comment: @freefaller good to know, what should be the solution to do what i intended to do from the first place than? thank you.

Comment: Remember - inline code blocks run on the **server**, they allow you to inject text directly into the text (the HTML, javascript) that will be sent to the **client** (i.e. the browser).  Once on the client, then the javascript will run

Comment: In the same way that you're sending `name` and `message` as parameters of `broadcastMessage` you can add another parameter for the class and use it that way.  But I'm not 100% sure exactly how you're wanting to use the content of `chatMessage`, so you need to figure out how to get that **to** the server before the broadcast

Comment: @freefaller i also wanted to send it as another argument in the `broadcastMessage` function but i have no way to edit it, it's inside some dll of the chat that i have no idea how to edit.

I just tried and i can't find any way to send it... do you or anyone else here have some idea how should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jquery val() function.

I also feel that the control isn't being found, which is why it's not setting it.

Try this instead.

```
$("#<%=chatMessage.ClientID%>").val('value from javascript');
```

Comment: No, you don't *have to use the jquery val() function*.  You **could** use it, but you can also do what the OP is already doing (i.e. using `document.getElementById` and `.value`)

Comment: @freefaller True. I usually feel safer using it though.

Comment: In that case, this doesn't really class as an answer, as it doesn't fix the issue the OP is having

Comment: @freefaller i also feel that chatMessage isn't being found.